# Vocal Cords Catching at Lowest Note

Tags: voice, voice-training, bass-voice

I'm working on increasing my vocal range, and I've gotten to G2 as the lowest note that I can sing clearly and loudly.  However, for some reason, whenever I try to sing F2, just one pitch lower, it's as though my vocal cords are catching on something, making the tone very unstable and sort of... it's hard to describe.  Like a combination of screechy and whiny.  I can *technically* hit the note, but whenever it's stable I can't increase the volume past a whisper, whereas even one pitch higher it's perfectly clear.

Yesterday when I managed to get it perfectly a few times I could feel the difference, so my main question is, what is actually happening?  I know the way to fix it - just practice more - but I'm really curious as to why it's like that currently.

Comment: It's possible that your ability to sing this note resets every day. I have similar low volume "problems" at the extreme ends of my singing range, and I find that I can temporarily increase my range with the proper vocal exercises.

Comment: It’s called “vocal fry” and it happens when your vocal chords are inefficiently resonating. You lack the control and air management for them to resonate the note, and that’s the resulting sound.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it doesn't sound like you are doing anything wrong.  From your description, I think you've just hit the low end of your vocal range.  We all have a low and high note that try as we might, we just physically can't get past.  Sounds like you found your low note.  I don't think practicing more is the solution - it will just be frustrating and might damage your voice.

Comment: I don't agree with you Jamie. If the singer is able to sing the note occasionally and presumably without forcing anything, it seems more like a matter of technique. Practicing is one way to overcome this limitation.